# discord.js Creating a Category & then creating channels inside of said category

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to create a set-up command, and make a dedicated category to my bot, for things like a log of updates & commands that were used. I've successfully made the category, and added 2 channels, but I can't seem to get it to auto place these inside the category.

Here's the code I currently have:

```
    message.guild.channels.create('Plotting', { type: 'category'} )
    message.guild.channels.create(`Log`, { type: 'text'}) 
    message.guild.channels.create('Summary', { type: 'text'})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in this code telling `Log` and `Summary` channels to be set in Plotting category. You need to pass `parent` option to set it up. Try this:

```
message.guild.channels.create('Plotting', { type: 'category'}).then(CategoryChannel => {
    message.guild.channels.create(`Log`, { type: 'text', parent: CategoryChannel});
    message.guild.channels.create('Summary', { type: 'text', parent: CategoryChannel});
}).catch();
```

More info on `options.parent` can be found [here](https://discord.js.org/?source=post_page---------------------------#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=create).

Also, remember to use `.catch()` block anywhere the code *may* not work.

Comment: Great, please mark my answer as the correct one :)